# Get random questions without duplicates

Tags: android

I have code source application Riddle Me and i wanna get random question in file xml without duplicacy.

Java Code :

```
public class TheGame extends Activity {
// Variables
InterstitialAd interstitial;
private Button[] word_btn;
private String lvl = "0";
private String coins = "0";
private String[] chars = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
        "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
        "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
private String[] word_array;
private String theWord = "999";
private String resultWord = "";
public Button[] randBtn;

Context mContext;
String TextFile,Ribbon;
TextView txt_ribon,txt_riddle;

Button btn_first,btn_bomb,btn_skip,btn_back,btn_ask;
boolean isLast=false;
StringBuilder sb;
private int winSound;
private int failureSound;
private int clickSound;
SoundPool sounds;
EarnCoin coin;
public TheGame() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 9) {
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    coin=new EarnCoin(getApplicationContext());
    initSounds();
    mContext=TheGame.this;
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()).append(File.separator).append(getString(R.string.app_name));

    txt_ribon=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_ribon);
    txt_riddle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_riddle);
    btn_first=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btn_bomb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn_skip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn_back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_ask=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


    // 12 orange buttons where appear letters of the word, and other letters
    randBtn = new Button[] { (Button) findViewById(R.id.char1),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char2),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char3),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char4),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char5),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char6),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char7),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char8),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char9),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char10),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char11),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char12) };
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    lvl = readData().split("\\|")[0];
    coins = readData().split("\\|")[1];
    if (Integer.parseInt(coins) < 0) {
        coins = "0";
    }
    parseXML(Integer.parseInt(lvl)-1);

    if(!isLast)
    {

        txt_riddle.setText(TextFile);
        txt_ribon.setText(Ribbon);
        word_array = getWord(theWord);
        createWord(word_array.length);
        randomChars();
        TextView lvl_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        lvl_txt.setText(" " + lvl + " ");
        TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        coins_txt.setText(coins);
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.reset_msg_1));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.reset_msg_2));
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                TheGame.this.finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.reset_title),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                writeData(getString(R.string.point_give));
                dialog.dismiss();
                TheGame.this.finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();
    }



    btn_first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_first_letter))) {
                            btn_first.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            coins = "" + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_first_letter)));
                            TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            coins_txt.setText(coins);
                            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins)));
                            word_btn[0].setText(word_array[0].toUpperCase());
                            word_btn[0].setOnClickListener(null);
                            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                                if (randBtn[i].getText().equals(
                                        word_array[0].toUpperCase())) {
                                    randBtn[i]
                                            .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    i = 12;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            // Check if sufficient coins
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheGame.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.first_letter_msg_3)).setIcon(
                    R.drawable.help);
            if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_first_letter))) {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.first_letter_msg_1));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            } else {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.first_letter_msg_2));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            }

        }
    });

    btn_bomb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_bomb))) {
                            btn_bomb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            coins = "" + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_bomb)));
                            TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            coins_txt.setText(coins);
                            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins)));
                            remove3Chars();
                        }
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            // Check if sufficient coins
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheGame.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.bomb_msg_3)).setIcon(R.drawable.help);
            if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_bomb))) {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.bomb_msg_1));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            } else {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.bomb_msg_2));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            }
        }
    });

    btn_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_skip))) {
                            btn_skip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            coins = "" + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_skip)));
                            TextView coins_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                            coins_txt.setText(coins);
                            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl) + 1) + "|"
                                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins)));
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                        }
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            // Check if sufficient coins
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    TheGame.this);
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.skip_msg_3)).setIcon(R.drawable.help);
            if (Integer.parseInt(coins) >= Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.how_much_for_skip))) {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.skip_msg_1));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            } else {
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.skip_msg_2));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.ok), dialogClickListener)
                .show();
            }
        }
    });


    if (Integer.parseInt(lvl) % Integer.parseInt(getString(R.string.number_of_stage_ad)) == 0) {
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
        interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        interstitial.show();
        if (!interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
            // Begin loading your interstitial.
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);
        }
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                interstitial.show();
            }
        });
    } 

    btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    btn_ask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String path=SaveBackground();
            File imagepath=new File(path);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/png");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imagepath));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initSounds()
{
    setVolumeControlStream(3);
    sounds = new SoundPool(4, 3, 0);
    winSound = sounds.load(this,R.raw.win, 1);
    failureSound = sounds.load(this, R.raw.failure, 1);
    clickSound = sounds.load(this, R.raw.click2, 1);
}

private void playSound(int i)
{
    if (coin.isSoundEnabled())
    {
        sounds.play(i, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F);
    }
}

// Function that generate black squares, depending on the number of letters
// in the word
private void createWord(int length) {
    LinearLayout world_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.world_layout);
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, length);

    word_btn = new Button[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        word_btn[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        word_btn[i].setText("");
        word_btn[i].setId(i);
        word_btn[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        word_btn[i].setTextSize(24);
        word_btn[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        word_btn[i].setLayoutParams(param);
        word_btn[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.matchbox);
        world_layout.addView(word_btn[i]);
        word_btn[i].setOnClickListener(charOnClick(word_btn[i]));
    }
}

// Function that generate random letters + word's leter on orange buttons
private void randomChars() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        randBtn[i].setOnClickListener(randCharClick(randBtn[i]));
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(25 - 0) + 0;
        randBtn[i].setText(chars[i1]);
    }

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(list);

    for (int x = 0; x < word_array.length; x++) {
        int value = list.remove(0);
        randBtn[value].setText(word_array[x].toUpperCase());
    }
}

// Fuction that clear wrong letter from black squares
private OnClickListener charOnClick(final Button button) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                if (randBtn[i].getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE
                        && randBtn[i].getText() == button.getText())
                    randBtn[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            button.setText("");

        }
    };
}

// Function for orange buttons
private OnClickListener randCharClick(final Button btn) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(clickSound);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (int i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
                if (word_btn[i].getText() == "") {
                    word_btn[i].setText(btn.getText());
                    i = word_array.length;
                }
            }
            createResult();
        }
    };
}

// Function that check if the word is correct and showing correct/wrong
// dialog
private void createResult() {
    resultWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word_array.length; i++) {
        if (word_btn[i].getText() != "") {
            resultWord += word_btn[i].getText();
        }
    }

    if (resultWord.length() == word_array.length) {
        if (resultWord.equalsIgnoreCase(theWord)) {
            showMyDialog(1, null);
        } else {
            showMyDialog(2, null);
        }
    }
}

// Function that transform the word to array
private String[] getWord(String str) {
    String[] chars = str.split("");
    List<String> selected_chars = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        selected_chars.add(chars[i]);
    }
    selected_chars.remove(0);
    return selected_chars.toArray(new String[selected_chars.size()]);
}

// //Function that showing dialogs: correct, wrong or zooming image
private void showMyDialog(final int type, String bmp) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(TheGame.this, R.style.dialogStyle);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView()
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dialog_bg);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    String points = ""
            + ((new Random().nextInt(10 - 3) + 3) + word_array.length);
    SmartImageView image = (SmartImageView) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
    Button dialogBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogBtn);
    TextView score = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.points);

    if (type == 1) {
        playSound(winSound);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.corect);
        dialogBtn.setText(" Continue "); // Next level button
        score.setText("+" + points);
        writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl) + 1) + "|"
                + (Integer.parseInt(coins) + Integer.parseInt(points)));
    } else if (type == 2) {
        playSound(failureSound);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gresit);
        dialogBtn.setText("  Try Again  "); // Try again button, restart
        // current level
        score.setText("-5");
        if (Integer.parseInt(coins) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(coins) <= 5) {
            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                    + (Integer.parseInt("0")));
        } else {
            writeData("" + (Integer.parseInt(lvl)) + "|"
                    + (Integer.parseInt(coins) - 5));
        }
    } else {
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        score.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        dialogBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ImageView coinicon = (ImageView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.dialogIcon);
        coinicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image.setImageUrl(bmp);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    dialog.show();

    dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (type > 0) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
//      // Button that open "Share on Facebook" dialog
//      fb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//              getBitmapFromView().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
//                      stream);
//              byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
////                Intent i = new Intent(TheGame.this, LoginFragment.class);
////                i.putExtra("image", byteArray);
////                i.putExtra("lvl", lvl);
////                startActivity(i);
//              dialog.dismiss();
//          }
//      });


// Function that save all user data. Current level, coins
private void writeData(String dataStr) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                openFileOutput("thewords.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(dataStr);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

// Function that read user data
private String readData() {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("thewords.dat");
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return ret;
}



// Function that hide 3 orange buttons (letters)
public void remove3Chars() {
    Button[] removeBtn = { (Button) findViewById(R.id.char1),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char2),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char3),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char4),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char5),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char6),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char7),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char8),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char9),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char10),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char11),
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.char12) };
    int x = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    while (x != 3) {
        int value = list.remove(0);
        if (!Arrays.asList(word_array).contains(
                removeBtn[value].getText().toString().toUpperCase())) {
            removeBtn[value].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            x += 1;

        }
    }
}

private void parseXML(int i) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("LevelData.xml");
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        LevelSAXParserHandler myXMLHandler = new LevelSAXParserHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        InputSource inStream = new InputSource(is);
        xr.parse(inStream);

        ArrayList<Level> cartList = myXMLHandler.getCartList();
        if(i>=cartList.size())
        {   
            isLast=true;
        }
        else
        {
            Level level=cartList.get(i); 
            theWord=level.getAnswer();
            TextFile=level.getTextId();
            Ribbon=level.getRibbon();

        }
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

public String SaveBackground()
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    RelativeLayout panelResult = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    panelResult.invalidate();
    panelResult.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    panelResult.buildDrawingCache();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int i = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int j = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(panelResult.getDrawingCache()), j, i, true);
    panelResult.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    String s = null;
    File file;
    boolean flag;
    file = new File(sb.toString());
    flag = file.isDirectory();
    s = null;
    if (flag)
    {
    }
    file.mkdir();
    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream1 = null;
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf("guess"))).append("_sound_").append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append(".png").toString();
    try {
        fileoutputstream1 = new FileOutputStream(new File(file, s));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = fileoutputstream1;

    StringBuilder stringbuilder1;
    bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileoutputstream);
    stringbuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
    stringbuilder1.append(sb.toString()).append(File.separator).append(s);

    try {
        fileoutputstream.flush();
        fileoutputstream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ""+stringbuilder1;

}}
```

and this LevelData.xml

```
<music><level>
    <levelNumber>1</levelNumber>
    <textId>If I have it, I don’t share it. If I share it, I don’t have it. What is it?</textId>
    <ribbon>KEEP</ribbon>
    <answer>SECRET</answer>
</level>

<level>
    <levelNumber>2</levelNumber>
    <textId>What gets broken without being held?</textId>
    <ribbon>KEEP</ribbon>
    <answer>PROMISE</answer>
</level>

<level>
    <levelNumber>3</levelNumber>
    <textId>You walk into a room with a match, a kerosene lamp, a candle, and a fireplace. Which do you light first?</textId>
    <ribbon>BOX</ribbon>
    <answer>MATCH</answer>
</level></music>
```

I hope you help me for get this question without duplicate in my app .  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: this looks like: *here is the code, do it for me* question, it would help you if, as specifically as possible, explain a bit with only the relevant code and let us know what have you tried so far to implement what you want

Comment: I will do it, but will charge to dive in this BIG CODE :)

Comment: simply store used question in an ArrayList and check against before getting the next one..

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of random integers:

```
parseXmlCount = ... // number of questions in XML

List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < parseXmlCount; i++) {
    indexList.add(new Integer(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(indexList);   // randomize
```

Now just interate through `indexList` to get non-repeating random indexes

Comment: how you git this question in xml and put ?